# How to share files between two computer with different subnet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, routing

I got 2 ip from my isp 10.247.49.152 & 10.247.49.153 The Main isp WAN is connected to a switch and then 153 goes directly to a computer and 152 goes to a wifi router and then to a computer. Like the following:

- 10.247.49.153 (subnet 255.255.255.0, default gateway 10.247.49.1) is the WAN of the switch and connected to a computer, **computer A**
- 10.247.49.152 (subnet 255.255.255.0, default gateway 10.247.49.1) is the WAN of a wifi router with DHCP server enabled (subnet 255.255.254.0, default gateway 10.247.49.1) which is come from the switch mentioned above.
- from the wifi router another computer, **computer B** is connected with ip address 10.247.49.154 (subnet 255.255.254.0, default gateway 10.247.49.1)

Now how would I transfer files between computer A & B?
Any help will be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: 1) you do not mention what operating system you use, so it's hard to suggest easiest method of file sharing 2) your configuration is broken; it shouldn't work as the router has the same network on both interfaces; first you need to change the DHCP to a different network (for computer B); with NAT you should then reach computer A from computer B, but not the other way; 3) is 254 in the third component of the subnet is a typo?

Comment: 1. operating system is windows 10 2. no there is not third component

Answer (score 0):

You did not state how the IP's are given to you, but you do not have to have the traffic go through a router before going to the computers, unless you want to NAT the traffic, and if you do then you should have both computers plugged in the LAN side of the router using private IP's.

You could use port forwarding in the router if you need to route incoming traffic to either of the computers.

If you are planning on binding the Public IP's to the computers, then the router is not needed and both computers can just get the public traffic directly from the switch with an uplink directly to the isp.

With use of a router, you may not even need two ip's, since the router can use a single public ip and everything behind it can use private IP's.

Another way to set this up is have the ISP uplink go directly to the switch (hopefully you have not bound the public ip to the switch if it is a managed switch).

One computer plugged directly into the switch with one of the public ip's bound to the computer. The second public ip should be bound to the WAN side of the router and the WAN should be plugged into the switch.

All other computers and devices should use the LAN side of the router and the router DHCP (scope) should be set up to hand out private ip's (192.168.x.x or 10.10.x.x is the most common)

Without an explanation about what you are trying to accomplish and why you have two ip's, unless you need to serve specific functions on two ip's, there are actually a number of ways to set this up.

The most common way, is use one ip, bound to the router and all devices behind using private ip's whether fixed or dhcp with port forwarding if specific functions one specific computers need access.

If both computers are using the same subnet (private ip's) there will be no problem sharing files.

Comment: "Another way to set this up is have the ISP uplink go directly to the switch (hopefully you have not bound the public ip to the switch if it is a managed switch).

One computer plugged directly into the switch with one of the public ip's bound to the computer. The second public ip should be bound to the WAN side of the router and the WAN should be plugged into the switch.

All other computers and devices should use the LAN side of the router and the router DHCP (scope) should be set up to hand out private ip's (192.168.x.x or 10.10.x.x is the most common)" my setting is exactly as you said

Comment: and I am trying to share files between the computer which is directly connected with switch and others are connected with the router DHCP